# Checking if a set of checkboxes have a certain number of options checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm coding a jQuery plugin that basically checks if a set of checkboxes groups have at least `x` options checked. A checkbox group is named as `name=group[]`. You'd call the plugin like:

```
$(':checkbox').checkpass({min: 1}) // Make sure at least one checkbox per group is checked
```

I've been working on this piece of code for a couple days trying to make it as short and fast as possible because I'm going to implement this on a very large `form`.  Is it possible to make it shorter/faster, or have I reached the limit?

You can check a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/).

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.checkpass = function(options) {

        var opt = $.extend({
            min: function() {
                return (min === 'undefined') ? 1 : min;
            },
            errorContainer: '<ul class="checkpass-errors">',
            errorWrap: '<li class="error">'
        }, options);

        var $ckboxes = this,
            names = [],
            num = 0,
            $errors = $(opt.errorContainer);

        $ckboxes.each(function() {
            var name = this.name;
            if (!~$.inArray(name, names)) {
                names.push(name);
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0, l = names.length; i < l; i++) {
            $checked = $ckboxes.filter('[name="' + names[i] + '"]:checked');
            if ($checked[opt.min - 1]) {
                num++;
            } else {
                if (opt.min > 0) {
                    var $err = $(opt.errorWrap),
                        _remaining = opt.min - $checked.length,
                        _name = names[i].match(/\w+/).toString()
                                .replace(/^\w/, function($0) {
                                    return $0.toUpperCase();
                                });
                    $err.html('<strong>' + _name +
                              ':</strong> Check ' +
                              _remaining + ' more.').appendTo($errors);
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            isValid: !! (num === names.length),
            errors: $errors
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: FYI: `shorted !== faster`

Comment: Well, in a way, yeah. I'm looking to make it tighter lets say. By removing unnecessary stuff like **toto2** suggested. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think you can also do "min = min || 1" instead of "min = (min === 'undefined') ? 1 : min"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an array for `names`, you could use some implementation of a set, which automatically skips duplications; see [here](http://community.service-now.com/blog/slightlyloony/4113).

Instead of keeping the `num` variable, I would just check if `errors` is empty to set `isValid`.

Actually, you can combine both suggestions by replacing `names` by an object that stores the unique names associated with their respective error message (or null if it passes).

```
{"animals[]" : someErrorMessage,  "drinks[]" : null, "colors[]" : someOtherErrorMessage}
```

You would need to replace your `for`-loop by a `for (name in names)` and you would only check if there is not enough check marks and add an error if that's the case.

I played with your fiddle and made a [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/d745G/25/):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.isIncomplete = function(options) {

        var opt = $.extend({
            min: function() {
                return (min === 'undefined') ? 1 : min;
            }
        }, options);

        var $ckboxes = this;
        var names = {};

        $ckboxes.each(function() {
            names[this.name] = null;
        });

        var errors = [];
        for (name in names) {
            var $checked = $ckboxes.filter('[name="' + name + '"]:checked');
            if ($checked.length < opt.min) {
                isValid = false;
                var _remaining = opt.min - $checked.length;
                var _name = name.match(/\w+/).toString().replace(/^\w/, function($0) {
                    return $0.toUpperCase();
                });
                errors.push('<strong>' + _name + ':</strong> Check ' + _remaining + ' more.');
            }
        }

        if (errors.length == 0) return null;
        else return errors;
    };
})(jQuery);


// Testing...
$('button').click(function() {
    var incompleteErrors = $(':checkbox').isIncomplete({
        min: 1
    });
    if (incompleteErrors) {
        ul = $('<ul>');
        for (var i = 0; i < incompleteErrors.length; i++)
        ul.append($('<li>').html(incompleteErrors[i]));
        $("#errors").html(ul);
    } else {
        $("#errors").html("");
        alert('Passed!');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Great ideas. I'm going to try to get rid of `num` which I don't think I need after all. Also, do you think that `dedupe()` will perform better than `$.inArray()`?

Comment: No, don't use `dedupe`!  That's the bad example they give before giving the 2 lines solutions with the Set (just a normal object -- aka associative array).  It's not clear that it's faster since there probably is some hashing done in the background, but at least it's much shorter.

Comment: I just tried getting rid of `num` and doing what you suggested and it works nicely. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/. I'm gonna give a try to your other suggestion.

Comment: See my edit.  I made some other changes, such as having an `isValid` variable which I change in the loop if there is an error and using an Object instead of an array, as I wrote above.

Comment: I think it would be better to wrap the error message in html outside of `checkPass`.  `checkPass` should just return the errors as strings and then the recipient of the result does whatever he wants: put the strings in html, print them to console.log, etc.  That would simplify `checkPass` quite a bit, both in the option set up at the start and in the for-loop.  You would still need to wrap the error messages in html elsewhere, but I think it does belong elsewhere.

Comment: I did update my example removing the html wrapping of the errors outside of the function.  I also renamed the function form `checkPass` to `isIncomplete`: it returns `null` if there is no error and an array of errors if there are some errors.

Comment: I combined both of your suggestions and I ended up keeping the `names` array and returning an `error` object `name: remaining`. This way I can also customize the message. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/

Answer (score 0):

No need for all that code! (unless I'm missing something)
This simple code should do:    (converted to a query plugin of course :)   )

```
function checkpass(a){
return (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length>a)
}
```

Comment: The idea is to check if at least one checkbox is checked per group. Your example looks for `a` checked in all checkboxes and doesn't work per group.